# Disabling code coverage for guard spec runs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, guard

For a variety of reasons, I find that running code coverage every time my files reload from guard is quite a burden. However, there doesn't seem to be a way to conditionally prevent SimpleCov from starting from the spec helper.

Is there a way to disable SimpleCov when run by guard, but not when I run it normally using `rake spec`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I ultimately found this solution:

1. Add an environment variable in your `Guardfile`:

   `guard :rspec, env: { 'NO_COVERAGE' => 'true' }`
2. Check for it from the spec helper:

   `SimpleCov.start :rails unless ENV["NO_COVERAGE"]`

Comment: The `env` option is now deprecated, adding the env var to `cmd` is the now recommended solution, e.g.: `guard :rspec, cmd: "NO_COVERAGE=true bin/rspec"`

Answer (score 4):

In your spec helper:

```
unless ARGV.any? {|e| e =~ /guard-rspec/ }
  SimpleCov.start
end
```

The idea here is that guard-rspec invokes rspec with a special guard-rspec formatter. Looking for that on the command line given gives you the hint that it was invoked from Guard, so you can just skip SimpleCov if that's there.

Answer (score 0):

In VsCode, I use Ruby Spec Command: `NO_COVERAGE=true bin/rspec` at the extension `Rails Run Spec`

Works too command line: `NO_COVERAGE=true bin/rspec spec/*_spec.rb` or `NO_COVERAGE=true bundle exec rspec spec/*_spec.rb`

Comment: I use the SimpleCov gem